# How to get directions from a set point to an input point

Tags: html, api, google-maps

I am new to using google maps API, but have managed to make it so you can input two locations and it will create directions and a direction list for you.

However I am trying to make it so you have one set point (long/lat) as the start location and you can input a destination and it will create the directions for you.

This is what I have so far:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Directions to nearby places</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB_MBMV60nG7Il1CNnJbmBUPrQ2kCMihe0&libraries=places&callback=initMap">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var getDirections;
    var directionCalculator = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    function initMap() {

        getDirections = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        var mySettings = {
            minZoomLevel: 20,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            mapTypeControl: false
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),mySettings);

        getDirections.setMap(map);
        getDirections.setPanel(document.getElementById("DirectionsList"));

    }

    function calcRoute() {
        var start = document.getElementById("Start").value;
        var end = document.getElementById("End").value;
        var request = {
            origin:start,
            destination:end,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING
        };

        directionCalculator.route(request, function (response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                getDirections.setDirections(response);
            }
        });
    }

    </script>
    </head>

   <body onload="initMap()">
   <p id="Time"></p>
   `<h1>Plan Your route</h1>`
 <form>
    <input type="submit" value="Reset" onclick="Reset()">
</form>
<p>
    <form action="routeDescription" onsubmit="calcRoute();return false;" id="routeForm">

        <input type="text" id="Start" value="" placeholder="Start Location">
        <input type="text" id="End" value="" placeholder="Destination">
        <input type="submit" value="Preview route">

    </form>
</p>
<br>
<div id="map" style="height:75%"></div>
<p>
    Here is how to get to your location
</p>
<div id="DirectionsList"></div>

<script>
        function Reset() {
            location.reload();
        }

        function Time() {
        var date = new Date();
        var time = date.toLocaleTimeString();
            document.getElementById("Time").innerHTML = time;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is your question?  What doesn't work?

Comment: Hi, currently I have two input boxes which take information about the start location and destination. How ever I want the start location to be set to a certain location all the time.+

Comment: What trouble are you having implementing that?  What is the "fixed point"?

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it is giving already a value to the input element with ID "Start", for instance:

```
<input type="text" id="Start" value=" value="Main St, CA">
```

or if you want to remove the #Start input element and only have one input for the destination , just replace this:

```
var start = document.getElementById("Start").value;
```

for your set point:

```
var start = "Main St, CA" // or in coordinates
```

If you want the origin to be your current location (of the device) you can use navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition():

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (location) {
console.log(location.coords.latitude); //here you have the value of lat
console.log(location.coords.longitude);//here you have the value of lng
//use them wisely
//more code
});
```